# как найти все txt файлы в папке c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, файловая-система

Как узнать все имена txt файлов в папке ?
Вот что смог я найти, если у вас есть предложение как реализовать это лучше, то пожалуйста предлагайте

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() 
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findTxt;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(L"\\in", &findTxt);

    cout << findTxt.cFileName << endl;

    FindClose(hFind);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если версия компилятора достаточно свежая, можно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::string path = ".";  // Ну, или где там нужно искать...

    for (auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(path))
        if ( p.path().extension() == ".txt" )
            std::cout << p.path().string() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, узнал о существовании такой библиотеки как filesystem, только пришлось поменять в настройках стандарт языка и все заработало)